# How can you use abstract classes to simplify creating models in MVC frameworks?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm starting to design an application to keep track of files for books. I want to be able to store information on paperback, hardback, audio, epub and kindle books separately. Even though there are some slight differences with the information that I need to store, these different types of books have a lot in common.

I was thinking it would be best to keep the common attributes in an abstract *Book* class and then make paperback, hardback, etc child classes that inherit from this class. I know that in MVC frameworks such as PlayFramework, your model will inherit from a base *Model* class. I've looked at and read about a lot of different MVC frameworks since college and it looks like a lot of MVC frameworks take this approach. Since a lot of languages doesn't support multiple inheritance, I can't have my models inherit from my abstract *Book* class and the frameworks base *Model* class that comes with a lot of MVC frameworks.

How can I get around this problem? Most of my experience is with Java with a bit of Ruby thrown in there. I'd prefer to use some Java MVC framework (Play, Spring, Grails) or Rails.

Could I have Book extend model and then have all of the subclasses extend book ? Instead of Book being an abstract class it would be a model that is never actually used.
eg.

```
Public Class Book extends Model
{
    //I would put common functionality here
}


//This would be one of the subclasses that I want to be able to inherit from book
Public Class PaperbackBook extends Book
{
    //put the code specific to paperback book in here
}
```

In my controllers I would only call PaperbackBook, HardbackBook, etc.

Comment: You could include a module with the shared behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Have `Book` extend `Model`. Tada.

In answer to your update, yes have `Book` extends `Model` and have all the other book types extends `Book`. AND, `Book` can still be abstract. There is nothing that says that a class that extends another class cannot be abstract.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question. As the OP's update to the post (done after this answer) suggests.

Comment: Well, it probably does, but can You really say that in the initial edit it was anything more than a comment placed as an answer?